# Terraform create a range variable

Tags: terraform

So I am creating this terraform resource where the TF generates the name of the room and its unique id. It works fine when I have 3 resources. But what happens in the case where I need 1000 resources, I do not want to append the names in the list as it will get bigger, is there a way to use range in this case with fixed name room and just keep on adding the number in the end ?

```
variable "list_of_rooms" {
  default = ["room1","room2","room3"]
}

resource "random_string" "string" {
  count            = 3
  length           = 14
  special          = true
  override_special = "/@£$"
}

resource "subject" "list" {
  for_each    = zipmap(list_of_rooms, random_string.string)

  room        = each.key
  unique_id   = each.value.result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [range](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/range) function. This is a working example:

```
variable "prefix" {
  type    = string
  default = "room"
}

variable "limit" {
  type    = number
  default = 10
}

locals {
  list_of_rooms   = [for element in range(var.limit) : tostring(element)]
  room_names      = values({ for element in local.list_of_rooms : element => format("%s%s", var.prefix, element) })
  string_results  = values(random_string.string)[*].result
}

resource "random_string" "string" {
  for_each = toset(local.list_of_rooms)

  length           = 14
  special          = true
  override_special = "/@£$"
}

output "subject_list" {
  value = zipmap(local.room_names, local.string_results)
}
```

Comment: thank you javierlga, your suggestion helped in my case.